# x86 - How do I detect virtualized code by looking at the assembly?

Tags: ida, x86, obfuscation, virtualizers, vmprotect

How can I detected virtualized code by say, vmprotect, obsidium or themida just by looking at the assembly code? I know that just looking at the PE section name would help, but I wanted to detect these obfuscators virtualization just by looking at the code. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 3):

That's tricky because obfuscated code often looks similar regardless of whether or not it specifically uses virtualization obfuscation. Most VMs ultimately have a similar high-level structure, as laid out in the following image, where there is a central point of dispatch to which almost all handlers ultimately return execution flow. (Although this is not true for all VMs; in so-called "direct threaded" VMs, the handlers pass control directly to one another instead of using a central dispatcher.)

[image: VM obfuscator schema]

So, one tempting answer to this question would be to look for a loop that ultimately transfers control into a table with pointers. However, VM protections quite often apply a lot of obfuscation to their interpreters -- dead code insertion, pattern-based obfuscation, constant unfolding, breaking the code up into chunks and interspersing `jmp` instructions between them -- so even if you are looking at the obfuscated code for a VM, the high level structure from the previous image might not be readily apparent. Another common thing for commercial-grade VMs to do is to obfuscate the "dispatcher" part -- for example, by applying some sort of transformation to the pointers in the table, and/or by replacing the `jmp` with something like `push`/`ret` instead.

Given that it can be difficult to determine this statically, it might be easier to determine it by tracing through the obfuscated code dynamically. If there seems to be a common location that the obfuscated code executes very frequently, that might be the fetch/decode/dispatch portion of the figure above. (Of course, as previously mentioned, direct-threaded VMs won't have this feature.)